# SSRS reporting executing cell data

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

So i'm not to sure how to research on this topic. My mission is to have a SSRS report  execute a select query that is stored in a table. my table has a (select * from MyTable) in a column. What I need the report to do is when the hyperlink is clicked it will open a new tablix with all the data. 
Any help we be appreciated.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but you can create dynamic SQL in your dataset query.

Put the SQL into a variable then execute it.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(max)

SELECT @SQL = SQL_FIELD 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE your criteria ...

EXEC(@sSQL)
```

After your SQL to set up your table, add your SELECT query.

You may have issues with permissions (as always) to EXEC.

Comment: Thanks i'll give that a try.